# Can I tell NetSuite Advanced PDF/HTML to treat data item as HTML?

Tags: netsuite, bfo

I’m new to NetSuite, just starting to try to develop an Advanced PDF/HTML template. I need to have a text data field contain HTML and have the report generate treat it as HTML.

The objective is that the data source that feeds NetSuite will generate HTML that varies based on the content of the data and other objects associated with it on another system, and to have the report engine render that HTML.

It doesn’t need to support terribly complex HTML basically just a table with columns/rows that may vary based on the data, including having rows that may contain another table.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Had an expert show me the solution. Here are the steps:

- Add the custom field and make it type Rich Text
- Develop an invoice template that looks like you want it to look, but put a placeholder string where you want the HTML to go (e.g. HTML_GOES_HERE)
- Write a JS scriptlet that will pull the HTML from the record and replace the placeholder. Import it into NetSuite and deploy it
- Add a custom action to the form where you view the invoice that will invoke the method in the JS scriptlet